# oneToMany relation entity does not save id field

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm trying to manage a oneToMany relation with [sonata admin](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_field_definition.html#advanced-usage-one-to-many)

Actually I'd like to have manyToMany relation like `sonata media bundle` has with `gallery > media`

A `HomePage` has many `Story`s which should be sortable etc.
Theres also `HomePageStory` to manage the relation, as suggested here:
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1231

**HomePage.orm.yml**

```
    oneToMany:
        HomePageStorys:
            targetEntity: HomePageStory
            mappedBy: HomePage
            cascade: ["persist", "merge", "remove"]
```

**HomePageAdmin.php**

```
       ->add(
          'HomePageStorys',
          'sonata_type_collection',
          array(
              'cascade_validation' => true,
          ),
          array(
              'edit' => 'inline',
              'inline' => 'table',
              'sortable' => 'position'
          )
      );
```

**HomePageStory.orm.yml**

```
    manyToOne:
        HomePage:
            targetEntity: HomePage
            joinColumn:
                name: homepage_id
                referencedColumnName: id

        Story:
            targetEntity: Story
            joinColumn:
                name: story_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

**HomePageStoryAdmin**

```
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $link_parameters = array();

        if ($this->hasParentFieldDescription()) {
            $link_parameters = $this->getParentFieldDescription()->getOption('link_parameters', array());
        }

        if ($this->hasRequest()) {
            $context = $this->getRequest()->get('context', null);

            if (null !== $context) {
                $link_parameters['context'] = $context;
            }
        }

        $formMapper
          ->add(
              'Story',
              'sonata_type_model_list',
              array('required' => false),
              array(
                  'link_parameters' => $link_parameters
              )
          )
          ->add('position', 'hidden');
    }
```

This works fine so far, as i can add HomePageStories on the HomePage Admin and pick a Story from the list inline.

But ***it just stores the `story_id` in the database while `homepage_id` stays empty***. If I set the homepage_id by hand, it's displayed in the homepage admin.

Any clue what I need to do to store the id of the parent entity (HomePage) on save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hm, seems as if you manually have to set the parent entity on the related children...

While not sure if it is really necessary or "the official way", the following did the trick:

**HomePageAdmin.php**

```
public function prePersist($homepage)
{
    foreach ($homepage->getHomePageStorys() as $homepagestory) {
        $homepagestory->setHomePage($homepage);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function preUpdate($homepage)
{
    foreach ($homepage->getHomePageStorys() as $homepagestory) {
        $homepagestory->setHomePage($homepage);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a "known" bug in Sonata. But the problem is, Sonata blames doctrine for this and vice versa. So it probably won't get fixed.